# Sync cPanel mail server to Microsoft Exchange Server

Tags: cpanel, mail-server

we have Microsoft exchange server 2019 locally and have a cPanel for our mail organization account, we need both server we want exchange server send and receive from cPanel server via pop3/smtp or anything is possible i mean exchange server be a client of cPanel server and send and received mail through cPanel server and data file stored in exchange server. is that possible ?